# Will both 'as' and 'when' be correct and natural here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, conjunctions, sentence-choice

> Three police officers are searching the offices in the hall. When/As
> they are done, they head for a door marked 'cafeteria'.

Hi. I can't figure out if both 'as' and 'when' would be correct here or only one of them. Could you please enlighten me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _When they are done_ implies _after they have finished searching_. _As they are done_ is less likely, but it could mean _because they have finished_.

Answer (score 1):

In this context 'as' fuctions as 'because'.

`As you are so excited, I would like to give you an opportunity to participate in this job.`

This is different from the continuous form of 'when'.

`As they finish their lunch, they pay the bill and walk out the restaurant.`

You would have to use 'when' here.